# My df has either one or two column. How to plot it without errors

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

My dataframe either look like this :

```
Appartement Maison
   0 1343       1
   1 1262       2
   3 1252       5
   4 1175       9
   5 1015       7
   6 531        5
```

Or depend ending on the query it could only have one of the two columns(Appartement, Maison)

My goal is to have a plot that works with the three combinations (1 columns Appartement/ 2columns/ 1 column Maison)

My code has errors as soon as the df don't have two columns:

```
figdist=px.bar(df_year, x=df_year.index, y=["Appartement", "Maison"], barmode='group')
```

How can I write a condition that would work in the three case?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If those are the only columns, why aren't you using:

```
figdist=px.bar(df_year, x=df_year.index, y=df_year.columns)
```

Comment: I already tried it it doesn't work KeyError: 0

Comment: Are you using Matplotlib

Comment: Plotly. I fixed it with figdist = px.bar(df_year, x=df_year.index, y=df_year.columns)

Comment: I think the problem was barmode='group' when there is only one column